# How do I do multiplexing on OkHttp?

Tags: okhttp, http2, multiplexing

I see some older questions about using SPDY (though the code has changed significantly since then), but no insights into how to properly leverage multiplexing and/or pipelining in OkHttp. I've gone through all the examples and have yet to see anything specifically referring to this.

Is this something that is automatically done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s automatic. If you have a server that supports HTTP/2, and a client that supports HTTP/2, it’ll do the right thing.